# How to generate different OTP token for different users using pyotp?

Tags: python, django, one-time-password

The code is as follows:

```
from pyotp import TOTP                                                                                                                                                                            

In [180]: import datetime                                                                                                                                                                                   

In [181]: import time                                                                                                                                                                                       

In [182]: now = time.time()                                                                                                                                                                                 

In [183]: secret = 'base32secret3232'                                                                                                                                                                       

In [184]: totp = TOTP(secret)                                                                                                                                                                               

In [185]: totp.at(now)                                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[185]: '447195'

In [186]: totp.at(now+20)                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[186]: '562455'

In [187]: totp.at(now+10)                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[187]: '447195'

In [188]: totp.at(now+30)                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[188]: '562455'

In [189]: totp.at(now+40)                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[189]: '562455'

In [190]: totp.at(now+50)                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[190]: '412255'

In [191]: totp.at(now+60)                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[191]: '412255'

In [192]: totp.at(now+70)                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[192]: '412255'

In [193]: totp.at(now+80)                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[193]: '722023'

In [194]: totp.interval                                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[194]: 30

In [195]: now                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[195]: 1582627336.8869653
```

My questions are as follows:

1. Why the code prints same token even when the arguments are different.
2. What if different users try to generate the token in the same time window see (20-40 seconds window), then will they get the same token. If yes, how to avoid it?

Comment: Different users should have different secrets

Comment: And, regarding 1 - the token changes every N seconds, but in your case N=30. So you get the same token for now+20, now+30, now+40, but a new one for now+50.